# Compute $P(X^2+Y^2 \leq 1 \mid X= x) $

Tags: probability

> $X$ and $Y$ are rv jointly continuous with pdf $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}$
>   for $0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. I want to evaluate
>   $P(X^2+Y^2 \leq 1 \mid X= x) $.

First of all, What confuses me is that value $X=x$. We know for continuous rv $P(X=x)= 0$. But if we try to evaluate the mentioned probabililty we have

$$ P(X^2+Y^2 \leq 1 \mid X= x) = \frac{P(x^2+Y^2 \leq 1 )}{P(X=x)} $$

by definition. But this is undenfined expression. is there a typo on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional density of $Y|X=x, $ $f_{Y|X=x}(x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{f(x,y)}{\int_0^x f(x,y)dy}=\frac{1/x}{\int_0^x 1/xdy}=1/x $ for $0<y<x,$ and $f_{Y|X=x}(x)=0$ otherwise. $P(X^2+Y^2\leq 1|X=x)=P(Y^2\leq 1-x^2|X=x)=P(0< Y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}|X=x)=\frac{\min\{x,\sqrt{1-x^2}\}}{x}.$